# MVVM not updating server data

Tags: java, android, mvvm, retrofit

I am a beginner on MVVM and tried it by following a tutorial. It is working and getting data from the server but the problem is that if data is changed in database then it is not changing in the app.

Is it possible that data gets updated automatically on the app when it is changed in MYSQL database or do i need to call api every time to get the latest data?

What am i doing wrong? Any Help?

**Main Activity:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewModel viewModel;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        viewModel = new ViewModel(this);

        viewModel.getPostsDataFromViewModel().observe(this, new Observer<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Post> posts) {
                for (int i = 0; i < posts.size() ; i++) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, posts.get(i).getId()+"\n"+posts.get(i).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
    public class ViewModel extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel {

    ApiRepo apiRepo;
    MutableLiveData<List<Post>> getPosts;

    public ViewModel(Context context)
    {
        apiRepo = new ApiRepo(context);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Post>> getPostsDataFromViewModel(){
        if(getPosts == null) {
            getPosts = apiRepo.getPostsDataFromRepo();
        }
        return getPosts;
    }
}
```

**ApiRepo:**

```
    public class ApiRepo {

    Context context;

    public ApiRepo(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<Post>> getPostsDataFromRepo()
    {
        final MutableLiveData<List<Post>> postsModel = new MutableLiveData<>();

        JsonPlaceholderApi jsonPlaceholderApi = RetrofitBuilder.getInstance(context).create(JsonPlaceholderApi.class);
        jsonPlaceholderApi.getPosts().enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {
                postsModel.setValue(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(context, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return postsModel;
    }
}
```

**RetrofitBuilder:**

```
public class RetrofitBuilder {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    private static final String BASE_URL = Constants.BASE_URL;
    //private static final String API_VERSION = BuildConfig.VERSION;

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = null;

    public static Retrofit getInstance(Context context) {
        if (retrofit == null) {

            httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            initHttpLogging();

            Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClientBuilder.build());


            retrofit = builder.build();

        }
        return retrofit;
    }


    private static void initHttpLogging() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(logging);
    }

    private static void initSSL(Context context) {

        SSLContext sslContext = null;
        try {
            sslContext = createCertificate(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.star_webddocsystems_com));
        } catch (CertificateException | IOException | KeyStoreException | KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(sslContext!=null){
            httpClientBuilder.sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), systemDefaultTrustManager());
        }

    }

    private static SSLContext createCertificate(InputStream trustedCertificateIS) throws CertificateException, IOException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        Certificate ca;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(trustedCertificateIS);
        } finally {
            trustedCertificateIS.close();
        }

        // creating a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        // creating a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        // creating an SSLSocketFactory that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        return sslContext;

    }

    private static X509TrustManager systemDefaultTrustManager() {

        try {
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
            TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
            if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:" + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
            }
            return (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(); // The system has no TLS. Just give up.
        }

    }

}
```

**JsonPlaceholderApi:**

```
 public interface JsonPlaceholderApi {

    @GET("posts")
    Call<List<Post>> getPosts();
}
```

**Constants:**

```
    public class Constants {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
    2021-09-15 19:06:00.501 4355-4355/? E/oc.mvvmtutoria: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-09-15 19:06:00.501 4355-4355/? E/oc.mvvmtutoria: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-09-15 19:06:00.501 4355-4355/? E/oc.mvvmtutoria: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-09-15 19:06:02.350 4355-4355/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/GraphicExt: Can't load libboost_ext_fwk
2021-09-15 19:06:02.350 4355-4355/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/GraphicExt: GraphicExtModuleLoader::CreateGraphicExtInstance false
2021-09-15 19:06:02.363 4355-4730/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
2021-09-15 19:06:02.390 4355-4730/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/IMGSRV: :0: GetRenderableInternalFormatInfoEntry: Unsupported renderable internal format 37808
2021-09-15 19:06:02.390 4355-4730/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/IMGSRV: :0: GetRenderableInternalFormatInfoEntry: Unsupported renderable internal format 37810
2021-09-15 19:06:02.390 4355-4730/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/IMGSRV: :0: GetRenderableInternalFormatInfoEntry: Unsupported renderable internal format 37809
2021-09-15 19:06:02.390 4355-4730/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/IMGSRV: :0: GetRenderableInternalFormatInfoEntry: Unsupported renderable internal format 37811
2021-09-15 19:06:02.390 4355-4730/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/IMGSRV: :0: GetRenderableInternalFormatInfoEntry: Unsupported renderable internal format 37812
2021-09-15 19:06:02.390 4355-4730/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/IMGSRV: :0: GetRenderableInternalFormatInfoEntry: Unsupported renderable internal format 37813
2021-09-15 19:06:02.390 4355-4730/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/IMGSRV: :0: GetRenderableInternalFormatInfoEntry: Unsupported renderable internal format 37814
2021-09-15 19:06:02.390 4355-4730/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/IMGSRV: :0: GetRenderableInternalFormatInfoEntry: Unsupported renderable internal format 37815
2021-09-15 19:06:02.390 4355-4730/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/IMGSRV: :0: GetRenderableInternalFormatInfoEntry: Unsupported renderable internal format 37816
2021-09-15 19:06:02.390 4355-4730/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/IMGSRV: :0: GetRenderableInternalFormatInfoEntry: Unsupported renderable internal format 37817
2021-09-15 19:06:02.390 4355-4730/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/IMGSRV: :0: GetRenderableInternalFormatInfoEntry: Unsupported renderable internal format 37818
2021-09-15 19:06:02.390 4355-4730/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/IMGSRV: :0: GetRenderableInternalFormatInfoEntry: Unsupported renderable internal format 37819
2021-09-15 19:06:02.390 4355-4730/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/IMGSRV: :0: GetRenderableInternalFormatInfoEntry: Unsupported renderable internal format 37820
2021-09-15 19:06:02.390 4355-4730/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/IMGSRV: :0: GetRenderableInternalFormatInfoEntry: Unsupported renderable internal format 37821
2021-09-15 19:06:02.394 4355-4355/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2021-09-15 19:06:02.424 4355-4730/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
2021-09-15 19:06:02.578 4355-4355/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2021-09-15 19:06:04.121 4355-4355/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2021-09-15 19:06:04.171 4355-4355/com.webdoc.mvvmtutorial E/GraphicExt: GraphicExtModuleLoader::CreateGraphicExtInstance false
```

Comment: What you can do is: return the ApiResult. Not as MutableLiveData it may be SUCCESS or ERROR. To be short, your response data or some null or error. and in ViewModel. you can do by this. getPosts.postValue(api response)

   private MutableLiveData<List<Post>> getPosts;

   LiveData<List<Post>> observePost = getPosts // Kotlin syntax. You can check in Java.
and in Activity or fragment.. observePost LiveData

Answer (score 0):

You can try directly observing on your

> apiRepo.getPostsDataFromRepo()

like following -

```
public LiveData<List<Post>> getPostsDataFromViewModel(){
  return getPosts = apiRepo.getPostsDataFromRepo();
}
```

no need to create another object in your view model class.

Comment: Thanks for answering but still not updating

Comment: please print your logcat trace, there must be some error in your network call

Comment: could you confirm, your 'postsModel.setValue(response.body());' is invoked ?

Comment: I have posted logcat in the question

Comment: the logcat is not showing anything related to your network calls, seems incomplete. Put a break point on your network call on response and validate the same.

Comment: 'postsModel.setValue(response.body());' its working only one time

Comment: what do you mean by one time, aren't you calling this method only once? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes i am calling this method only once but what i want is if data is changed in mysql database it should be updated here as well. Is it possible in mvvm? i have watched tutorials on yt and they said its possible

Comment: or do i need to call api everytime as we usually do to get latest data from server?